# Azure Web Job writes files in a website's directory

Tags: azure-webjobs

I attached a Web Job to my Azure website. The webjob prepares a file and I want to save it on a proper folder in the website.

`Environment.CurrentDirectory` run on the script returns a path under a Temp directory:  `Temp\jobs\triggered\WEBJOBNAME\q0uwrohv.x5e`

I tried to go down on the directory tree:

```
string path = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"..\..\..\..\..\Data")
```

But it doesn't work:

```
C:\DWASFiles\Sites\WEBSITENAME\Temp\jobs\triggered\WEBJOBNAME\q0uwrohv.x5e\..\..\..\..\..\Data
```

How to make and save files from WebJob to a particular path?

I don't want to use blob store.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The path for the root of your Azure Web Site is (usually) `d:\home\site\wwwroot`.
`d:\home` is also stored in an environment setting called `%HOME%`.

To get more insight on the different paths you can use on your site go to:
`https://{sitename}.scm.azurewebsites.net`, there' you'll have the **Debug Console** where you can browse through your site and **Environment** to see all the environment variables you can use.

Your WebJob will have access to the same paths/environment as your Web Site.

For more information on this administration site go to:
http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/03/28/windows-azure-websites-online-tools-you-should-know-about-2/

Comment: Use `WEBROOT_PATH` environment variable instead of hard-coding the `d:\home\site\wwwroot` path.

Comment: Using the Kudo Debug Console made this a trivial task to implement

Comment: When attempting to write to `d:\home\site\wwwroot`, I receive an `UnauthorizedAccessException` from the WebJob.

Comment: try the same with debug console (write a file to wwwroot), does that work?

Answer (score 1):

try the following instead of putting a file location in the value parameter just put this as I show you here

you can do it in the `app.config` file

```
add key="app:TempFolderPath" value="~/temp/"/
add key="app:TempReportDirectory" value="~/temp/"/
```

the web job will automatically put in this location of

```
D:\local\Temp\jobs\continuous\ImporterWebJob\yex3ad1c.3wo\~\temp\...your file...
```

I hope this will not give you any errors.