# How to access my website's PHP files using Windows Azure WebJobs?

Tags: php, azure, azure-webjobs

I have a website hosted on Azure.

My website files are stored in `wwwroot`. I'm using Azure WebJobs to schedule some tasks. This WebJob is a simple PHP file. It needs to access my websites files.

For the purpose of this discussion, let's say I want to edit my `index.php` or `images/` folder which is located in the website root.

My WebJob runs from this location: `C:\DWASFiles\Sites\<sitename>\Temp\jobs\triggered\<jobname>\kjsx2sne.7sa\script.php`

How can I access my website's files? Where are they located? I tried to access `C:\DWASFiles\Sites\<sitename>\`. However I'm getting a `Permission denied` error in PHP.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24156185/azure-web-job-writes-files-in-a-websites-directory), the path for the root of an Azure Website is (usually) `D:\home\site\wwwroot`

Comment: Use `WEBROOT_PATH` environment variable instead of hard-coding the `d:\home\site\wwwroot` path.

Comment: I am receiving `System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data is denied.`