# Physical path in Azure WebJobs

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I am trying to deploy webjob in azure. It is an existing console app that does a file copy using SFTP.

The appsetting in the app.config file is like below :

```
<add key="IdentityFile" value="C:\Temp\Uploads\UploadTest.ppk"/>
```

I know I have to set this in AppSettings section of the AppService but I am not sure what is equivalent to "C:\Temp" in Azure.

Could someone please guide me? Thank you

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24156185/azure-web-job-writes-files-in-a-websites-directory.  You can read the `%HOME%` environment variable to get the root of the website, and then I presume that you'd know the path under that folder.  Be aware - Azure can recycle and redeploy the app to a different machine and local files are lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Azure App Service, you can still rely on `%TMP%` to find the temp folder. The folder it goes to is `D:\local\Temp`, so you could change your config to `D:\local\Temp\Uploads\UploadTest.ppk`.

Note that you can change this by setting an `IdentityFile` App Setting in the Azure Portal, instead of changing it in the physical app.config file.